# Shrinking logical volume on partition to copy VirtualBox VM to new .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, gparted, lvm

I've created an Ubuntu 22.04 virtual box VM on a Windows 10 host machine. I've allocated 600GB virtual memory size for a dynamically expanding disk in virtual box. When I created this VM I had thought my ssd was 1TB but it is only 500GB.

Recently the VM has grown to 277GB which combined with the host windows filesystem had filled up the ssd. I was able to shrink it back down to 60GB, but would like to reduce the virtual memory size to ensure this does not happen again.

Virtual Box (7.0.12) does not yet support shrinking the virtual size. The solution I'm trying to implement is to create an empty .vdi image file that has the correct virtual size limit. I then attempt to clone the previous disk using gparted and dd. Problem I am facing is that gparted cannot reduce the size of the main partition /dev/sda3 because the partition has two logical volumes (root and swap_1) in one volume group (vgubuntu).

I know there are easier solutions out there that include increasing the size of my ssd and creating a new VM from scratch. At this point I'm treating this as a learning exercise and would like to solve this problem using this method if it's possible.

I've tried the following:

1. Cloned VM as a backup.
2. Downloaded Gparted iso image and assigned it first in the boot order
   in virtual box.
3. Created a .vdi image with 200GB virtual memory size, did not expand
   it to full capacity. Added this to the SATA port in virtual box.
4. Ran VM using gparted iso. Image below shows that /dev/sda3 partition
   is allocated 500GB and is 100% used. This is not the case in
   reality, my .vdi file is 70 or so GB. [gparted showing logical volume is 100% used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7F6Lv.png), [lvdisplay showing logical volume and group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCyGq.png)

I then attempted to reduce the size of the root logical volume using: `sudo lvreduce -L 100GB -n /dev/vgubuntu/root`. This seemed to work [gparted showing unused memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBQow.png)

However when I go to partition the disk I get the following error message:
[gparted error screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpnMg.png)

Can someone explain why this error is coming up?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to resize the file system, the logical volume and the volume group.
To resize the logical group and filesystem together you use the following command `sudo lvresize -L -200G  --resizefs /dev/vgubuntu/root`

`-200G` is how many gigabytes you want to shrink by,

`--resizefs` as the name suggests is to resize the file system.

You then need to move the swap_1 logical volume to the newly freed space that used to belong to the root volume.
To do this run `sudo pvs --segments /dev/sda3` to view the physical volumes.
Then `sudo pvmove --alloc anywhere /dev/sda3:<start_byte>-<end_byte>`. The /dev/sda3:<start_byte>-<end_byte> is found under the 'PE Ranges' heading from the output of the previous command.

This image shows an example: [Moving logical volume to newly freed space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTzt.png)